# Characterization of the matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $A$ is an invertible matrix and let $X$ be such that $AX+XA=2I$. Does this imply that $X=A^{-1}$?

I have tried simple algebra manipulations but I have not been able to conclude. For a simple example of 2x2 matrices I found it was true.

Comment: can you show a proof??

Comment: it is obvious that if $X=A^{-1}$ then $AX + XA=2I$... i am asking about the other direction

Comment: $X=A^{-1}$ is the unique solution if and only if no two eigenvalues of  $A$ sum to zero.

Comment: The interesting question here is for which $A$ the endormorphism $X\to AX+XA$ is invertible. I'm not sure how to say anything intelligent in that direction.

Comment: ...although you can google "[anticommutative matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391334/anti-commutative-matrices)" for inspiration.

Comment: @user1551 That is interesting, you should post as an answer if you have a proof.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is No, here is a counter example
$$A=\left[\matrix{0&1\cr 1&0}\right],\quad X=\left[\matrix{1&1\cr 1&-1}\right]$$ here
$A^{-1}=A\ne X$ while $AX+XA=2I$.

Comment: can you think about any assumption on $A$ that would make the result true?

Comment: @latorrefabian, true if $X$ and $A$ commute.

Answer (score 0):

I believe user1551's comment under the question is correct, at least if $A$ is diagonalizable. He/she claims that the solution is unique if and only if no two eigenvalues of $A$ sum to zero. To see this, observe that there are multiple solutions if and only if there is a non-zero matrix $Y$ such that $AY+YA=0$. If $A$ has a diagonal form $D=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots)$, this is equivalent to the existence of a non-zero $Z$ such that $DZ+ZD = 0$. Written explicitly in terms of the matrix elements of $Z$, that means $\lambda_i z_{ij} + z_{ij}\lambda_j=(\lambda_i+\lambda_j)z_{ij}=0$ for all $i,j$. This has a non-zero solution if and only if at least one of the terms $\lambda_i+\lambda_j$ is zero.

I am not really sure about the case when $A$ is not diagonalizable. You could perhaps use the [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) of $A$ to generalize the condition above.