# How do I solve $AB+BA=C$ for $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

It might be a silly question... But

> how do I solve
>   $$A\,B + B\,A = C$$
>   for $A$???

Like... Is there a solution of the kind $A = f(C, B^{-1})$ or even $A = a\,C\,B^{-1} + b\,B^{-1}\,C$ for some $a$ and $b$?

Thanks!

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Guys, think you for the answers up to now, but Im afraid the comments are precise in the sense that I want a explicit form for $A$.

Comment: Related; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391334/anti-commutative-matrices

Comment: Note that if $A$ and $A'$ are two solutions to
$$XB+BX=C,\tag{1}$$
then the matrix $D:=A-A'$ satisfies
$$DB+BD=0.\tag{2}$$
Conversely if $A$ satisfies $(1)$ and $D$ satisfies $(2)$ then $A+D$ also satisfies $(1)$. So to find all solutions to $(1)$, it suffices to find all solutions to $(2)$ and a single solution to $(1)$. The solutions are then of the form $$A+c_1D_1+c_2D_2+\cdots+c_nD_n,$$
though determining general expressions for $A$ and the $D_i$ in terms of $B$ and $C$ does not seem tractable.

Comment: It might happens that it was really a "silly me" situation...
I just realise that I can make $A=a\,C\,B^{-1} $ solve for $a$
then I think I would get $A = C{(C + BC{B^{ - 1}})^{ - 1}}C{B^{ - 1}}$
But Im having a hard time putting $A$ back and getting only $C$ in the rhs.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Servaes. I think I se your point, but maybe you need only ONE term in that "serie" (see my previous comment). Now I have to put back and see if I get $C$ again

Comment: No, the number $n$ is the dimension of the space of matrices anticommuting with $B$. This varies for varying $B$.

Comment: Thank you @Servaes, do you think the solution in my previous comments apply?

Comment: No, I think it makes no sense at all. It is very easy to find examples where there are solutions none of which take the form $A=aCB^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point where it's failing? (the solution using $s\,C\,B^{-1}$? Could it be ONE solution (rather than THE solution?).
Something tells me that I made a mistake somewhere... But I can't find where. Im still trying to find if I can get C back from it...

Comment: Ok found it... I considered $a$ as a scalar and the solution came out as a matrix... Back to the original problem them... I'll analise your proposition with the anti-computation. Thank you!

Comment: In Servaes's (1) and (2), he is alluding to the fact that this is an inhomogeneous system of linear equations in the $n^2$ entries of $A$. So in principle, you can solve by row reducing an annoyingly big matrix.

Comment: Hello @user52817, yes actually numerically I can solve by enumerating the variables $a_{1,1}, a_{1,1}, ...$ and making a big linear system. Maybe we can even show that the dimension of the null space is not zero (as @Servaes) mentioned with the inomogeous argument. But I would like a "closed" solution in the sense that I will have to differentiate, integrate, etc... laler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that for every eigenvalue of $B$, say $\lambda$, one has $Re(\lambda)>0$. Then the equation $AB+BA=C$ has a unique solution

$A=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-tB}Ce^{-tB}dt$.

EDIT. More generally.

$\textbf{Proposition}$. Let $A,B,C$ be complex $n\times n$ matrices, $(\lambda_i)_i=spectrum(A),(\mu_i)_i=spectrum(B)$. Assume that , for every $i,j$, $Re(\lambda_i+\mu_j)>0$.

Then the equation $AX+XB=C$ has the unique solution

$X=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-tA}Ce^{-tB}dt$.

$\textbf{Proof}$. We stack the matrices into vectors, row by row.

i) Notice that $f=A\otimes I+I\otimes B^T:X\mapsto AX+XB$ is one to one. Indeed, $0\notin spectrum(f)=(\lambda_i+\mu_j)_{i,j}$. Moreover, $-f$ is asymptotically stable (its eigenvalues have a negative real part).

ii) Let $g_t=e^{-tA}\otimes e^{-tB^T}:C\mapsto e^{-tA}Ce^{-tB}$; then $g_t=e^{-tf}$ and

$\int_0^{\infty} g_t(C)dt=\int_0^{\infty}g_tdt C=f^{-1}C=X$.

Comment: Hello there loup blanc, Thank you for the answer. Actually, that is EXACTLY my original question %-) I didn't post it like so because I manage to arrive at the $AB+BA=C$ equation (seemed simpler to ask here).
But you were bulls eye on this one! Tha's exactly what I need to know! Given B and C, what is the value of that integral.
And yes, all my eigenvalues are negative for $-B$ (positive for $B$ in your case)
So cool that you arrived at my initial problem! Very good of you!!!

Comment: Hello @loup blank, thank you again for the edit. I think this solution is really neat! Thanks! But I'm affraid that its rather related to the enumeration of variables $a_{i,j}$ and solution of the remaining linear system. One thing that I find interesting though is that, somehow the argument that we have a nulspace (or some kind of inomogeneity as mention by seevaes before) might mean that we have multiple solutions, which can be the case when the eigenvalues are not negative. This is just a superficial comment, I didn't analise any of that. Just  seemed cool at first sight.

Comment: The solution of $AX+XB=C$ is unique iff for every $i,j$, $\lambda_i+\mu_j\not= 0$. If you are satisfied by my post, then accept it, that is,  give it the green chevron.

Comment: @runway44 that was my exact reaction... It seems so simple, right? %-)

Comment: @loupblanc please allow me to wait a bit because as I said, I would like a "closed" form for the solution because I'll, later, differentiate, integrate, etc... (the solution in termos of other variables). Anyway you were the closest up to now and also the very usefull comment by Servaes. Thank you!

Comment: @loupblanc, thank you very much. I think I might be able to do my calculations with the kroneker operator and have
$X=fˆ{-1}vec(C)$. I think that was what you meant for the solution (which works, of course).